# Grails Application Shutting Down

Tags: grails

We have two grails applications, one running on 2.5, the other on 3.0.9 that shut down automatically with nothing in the logs. We have correlated that this is shutdown is consistent with a qualys scan that is running on our system.  The shutdown appears to be graceful as the lock file we use is not left behind, thus indicating that the app did not crash.

Equally puzzling is that this does not happen each and every scan but when it does it is shortly after

Of note: We do not have any of the spring boot actuator url's mapped nor is the shutdown actuator enabled.  We are wondering if there is some other way a web request (or some other action) that could possibly shut the application down in this manner.

OS: linux RHEL6 VM
Grails: 2.5 & 3.09
Groovy: 2.4.4
Java: OpenJDK 1.8.0.51

Comment: Are you able to exclude the lock file from the scan?

Comment: Show us your tomcat logs: stacktrace / catalina / access.

Comment: @majkeloThat's the problem.  The tomcat logs are empty (which is telling me nothing from the scan is getting thru).  The ssl access logs have the scan hits, then there is a gap until the next scan 8 hrs later which returned 503 errors from the jump.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa I will investigate that and get back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem with the 2.5 version was based on a plugin that we created with some help from the grails team.  As it turned out there was a line in the code that was setting killListenerPort = connector port + 1 which turned out to be 8081 which the qualys scan would hit and shutdown the app.

As far as the 3.0.9 app, we have not been able to replicate the issue so the embedded spring boot tomcat starter plugin is safe from this exploit.